# VSTO & Office.context.document.settings

Tags: excel, vsto, napa

Is it possible to access Office.context.document.settings from VSTO?

We have an VSTO AddIn that currently writes to the CustomXML in Excel workbooks. We would like to make it Napa/O365 compatible. Since Napa can't read CustomXML parts in Excel we want to write to Office.context.document.settings, hence the question above.

Or is there a better way to share storage between VSTO and Napa in a Excel workbook?

Ron.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript for Office API can't be used in a VSTO solution, as it requires a web context.  Your desktop add-in solution would have to be ported to use the web-based APIs and tools.